# manually set an order number with auto increment in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a MySQL code to set an order number with auto increments.

This is already in the database, but I want to change the order number
I hope some one can help.

Thank you very much
Regards flemming

Comment: What do you mean whith 'change the order number'?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the autoincrement increment and offset as says the documentation in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=x;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=y;
```

where x & y are the values you need to set